# Retrofit got UnknownHostException calling url with '-' or '_' in it

Tags: android, exception, retrofit2

I'm trying to call an api in my Android application. and the url template is like:

`test--.domainname.com/api/xxxxxx`

I'm using Retrofit2 but I got the follow Exception:
`Unable to resolve host "test---.domainname.com": No address associated with hostname`

I'm sure I can got the success response from the url using browser. And Retrofit2 works very well for other api without '-' or '_' in the path.

Is the exception a feature of okHttp or Retrofit? or just someone can help me with this problem?

---

I've read the [1552 issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1552) of Retrofit. And I'm sure I add the correct scheme.

Comment: `-` at the end of subdomain is illegal. Are you sure about your link? Can you give a real link?

Comment: @TruongHieu In fact, my App allow customer define their own subdomain. I know symbol `-` is incorrect, but I can't control customer's behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test--.domainname.com/api/xxxxxx` this subdomain is ended with symbol `-`, this is incorrect. So check your link first.